# Как применить одно свойство сразу к нескольким элементам?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-faq

К примеру, есть несколько текст боксов и чек бокс. Если свойство Checked у чек бокса true, то Visible у текст боксов также true и наоборот. Можно было бы прописать свойство каждого текст бокса отдельно, но чет некрасиво получается.
Пример некрасивого кода:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            textBox3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код, который вы написали, чтобы решить свою задачу.

Comment: отредачил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Ох уж эти думы о красивости...
Делов на несколько секунд.

Способ с обработчиком события:

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = checkBox.Checked;
    textBox2.Visible = checkBox.Checked;
}
```

Способ с привязкой данных:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", checkBox, "Checked");

textBox2.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Visible), checkBox, nameof(CheckBox.Checked));
```

Показал, что можно использовать как введённые вручную литералы, так и `nameof`.